# SQL Table as matrix (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, matrix

I have some interesting complex puzzle, complex for me at least.
So this is the problem ....

I have a simple table that looks like this

```
Create table User(UserID int, DaysCount int, Date int)
```

Then I have simple select that based on DaysCount gives User some specific grade going from 1 to 4 and adding that to some temporary table.

```
Select UserID, 
(case
when DaysCount >= 0 and DaysCount <= 10 then 1
when DaysCount >= 11 and DaysCount <= 20 then 2
when DaysCount >= 21 and DaysCount <= 30 then 3
when DaysCount >= 31 and DaysCount <= 40 then 4
end) as Grade, Month
Into #A
from Users
where Date = 20150131

Select UserID, 
(case
when DaysCount >= 0 and DaysCount <= 10 then 1
when DaysCount >= 11 and DaysCount <= 20 then 2
when DaysCount >= 21 and DaysCount <= 30 then 3
when DaysCount >= 31 and DaysCount <= 40 then 4
end) as Grade, Month
Into #B
from Users
where Date = 20150228
```

And then this is complex part where I have a hard time ... I need to make a query that will select from temp. tables and insert data into new table (this table needs to look like matrix) and it will look like this.

```
      Here is how table should look at end

 UserID      1    2    3     4          Date

   11        1    0    0     0        20150131  
   11        0    0    1     0        20150228
   13        0    1    0     0        20150228
   14        0    0    0     1        20150131
```

Thank you for help and please let me know if you don't understand what my problem exactly is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, all the temporary tables are not necessary, you can simply extract this as a single query from your `users` table, but rather than using a single case expression that returns a value between 1 and 4, use 4 case expressions that return 1 or 0:

```
SELECT  UserID,
        [1] = CASE WHEN DaysCount >= 0 AND DaysCount <= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        [2] = CASE WHEN DaysCount >= 11 AND DaysCount <= 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        [3] = CASE WHEN DaysCount >= 21 AND DaysCount <= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        [4] = CASE WHEN DaysCount >= 31 AND DaysCount <= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        Date 
FROM    Users
WHERE   Date IN ('20150131', '20150228');
```

Or if you prefer the more traditional column aliases:

```
SELECT  UserID,
        CASE WHEN DaysCount >= 0 AND DaysCount <= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [1],
        CASE WHEN DaysCount >= 11 AND DaysCount <= 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [2],
        CASE WHEN DaysCount >= 21 AND DaysCount <= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [3],
        CASE WHEN DaysCount >= 31 AND DaysCount <= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [4],
        Date 
FROM    Users
WHERE   Date IN ('20150131', '20150228');
```

Comment: This actually works like a charm ... thank you our T-SQL guru!

Answer (score 0):

Since they are intervals of ten, here's a shorter way to write it.

```
SELECT  DaysCount, 
        [1] = CASE WHEN dcID <= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        [2] = CASE WHEN dcID  = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        [3] = CASE WHEN dcID  = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        [4] = CASE WHEN dcID  = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM Users
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CEILING(DaysCount/10.0)) CA(dcID)
WHERE [Date] IN ('20150131', '20150228');
```